# no colors in scripts

Tags: 16.04, vim

In ubuntu desktop 16's terminal (fresh install), I see colors on the main command line.

But if I'm inside a script, like `vi ~/.bashrc`, it's all of the same color.

How can I get colors when editing scripts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vim` instead of `vi`. The feature you're looking for is called *syntax highlighting*. It should be enabled by default in `vim`, and it's typically not enabled in `vi`.

Comment: Thank you, not only it works, but after installing `vim`, I can use `vi` and _syntax highlighting_ works. That's because `vi` is pointing to `vim` : _/usr/bin/vi -> /etc/alternatives/vi_ , _/etc/alternatives/vi -> /usr/bin/vim.basic_

Comment: @trogne It was pointing to Vim even before you install `vim`, but to `vim.tiny` instead.